# Horizontal Header to Large in QtDesigner

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qt-designer

I am building a Gui in QtDesigner but i do not understand how i add a "dynamical property":
I try to add a QTable Widget but the Header of the Columns are to large (The Text is just 2 letter in the Columns).
For Space reasons in my Gui i just need them to be as big as the text is (or let us say 4 letters)

i found the 
QHeaderView::ResizeToContents method but i do not know how to use it- is there a way to do this in QtDesigner?

I am new to this and i do not know how to change the code behind the Gui...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PyQt, the main purpose of Qt Designer is to create the main GUI structure of your application. It only allows a subset of the available properties to be modified for any given widget, and it cannot be used to write the application's main logic.

Instead, the idea is to generate a python module from the ui file created by Qt Designer, and then import it into your application where you can do the remaining setup code, connect signals, write all the event handlers, etc.

Let's say you've created a `ui` file with Qt Designer and named it `mainwindow.ui`.

You would then generate the python module like this:

```
pyuic4 -o mainwindow_ui.py mainwindow.ui
```

Next, you would write a separate `main.py` script that imports the GUI classes from the generated module, and creates instances of them as needed.

So your `main.py` would look something like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from mainwindow_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        header = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
        header.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The base-class here must be same as the top-level widget in Qt Designer (i.e. usually either QMainWindow, QDialog, or QWidget). Also, the `objectName` property of the top-level widget is used to generate the classname of the imported GUI class (with "Ui_" prepended to it). The example above assumes this was set to "MainWindow".

The `objectName` properties of all the other widgets will become attributes of the `MainWindow` class, so that they can be accessed easily in the rest of your code. Because of this, it's important that you always set the `objectName` properties to descriptive names (i.e. not "pushButton_1", "pushButton_2", etc).

Comment: is it possible to change the source code and add the part for the header and see the preview in qt designer aftewards?

Comment: @user2956831. No (well, not unless you want to go to the trouble of writing a [custom widget plugin](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq26-pyqtdesigner.html)). But why not just run the main.py script if you want to view the changes?

Comment: yes i see the changes in my main.py when i reload the file, thanks